# Add Custom Attribute to Request Header Angular 6

Tags: angular, httprequest, angular6

Trying to add custom attribute to HttpHeader request but it doesn't seem to be sent .

```
  getUserInfo(){
    this.headers.append('CustomerId', 'ad34e1b2'); 
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl+"getInfo",{ headers:this.headers });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import new HttpHeaders

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

create an instance of it in your function

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.append('CustomerId', 'ad34e1b2');
```

or creating multiple you can add like

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders(
{'abc':'22',
'abc2':'111',
'abc4':'444'}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `post()` method parameters of `HttpClient` module you will able to see the acceptable parameters as below:

```
/**
* @license
* Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
*
* Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
* found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
*/

 /**
 * Construct a POST request which interprets the body as JSON and returns the full response.
 *
 * @return an `Observable` of the `HttpResponse` for the request, with a body type of `Object`.
 */
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe: 'response';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>;
```

which means the function accepts `url`, `body` and `options` as a main acceptable parameters. you can specify the custom headers by creating a function which will accept the header name and value. like this in case of single custom header in case of multiple headers you are free to write your own version of function.

```
private setHeaders(customHeader: string, value: string): HttpHeaders {
const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  customHeader: value,
});
return headers;
}
```

and lately don't forget to import these libraries.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```